# Xcode invisible elements

Tags: xcode, button, uisegmentedcontrol

I don't know what happened. Elements items like buttons or segmented control are invisible in main storyboard. Cellphone is the same.

I put the image, of what I mean

[image]

Comment: You may prefer [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Spanish swift o xcode comunity is very small

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you accidentally changed the view's (or window's) Tint Color to white. (Or you could even have turned it to Clear color, or no color at all.)

This would cause the text of the button or segmented control to be invisible, because it is white on white. The segmented control has a border but it would turn white too. So you wouldn't be able to see anything.

There are two places to look to fix this. Look at the Tint popup of your view controller's View in the Attributes inspector.

[image]

Also look at the Global Tint popup in the File inspector for the whole storyboard.

[image]

[**EDIT** It turned out to be the Global Tint.]

Comment: Excellent! Was it the view tint or the global tint?

Comment: But which one was it?

Comment: Sorry only read global tint haha
global tint it was the problem.
because when add a new viewcontroller same thing happened