# Xcode 10 storyboard UI components are not visible and painfully slow?

Tags: xcode, xcode9, xcode10

My code was working fine (showing UI properly) when I had Xcode 9 and I removed it from the application folder (could not update as it had installed using another apple id) and reinstall the Xcode 10 from the Appstore.

Now Xcode storyboard not showing any added UI elements colors or anything and I removed Xcode 10 and installed Xcode 9 again but problem remains same.

UI screen shot of storyboard.

[image]

I tried removing Xcode in this way:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app
/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist
~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode
~/Library/Application Support/Xcode
~/Library/Developer/Xcode
~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator
```

Then I tried installing macOs Mojave and install XCode 10 again from the Appstore. Issue still remains. I tried cleaning derived data, xuserdata and everything.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52416349/341994

Comment: Hi Matt, I tried but its not working.

Comment: Just a heads-up that I'm seeing exactly the same issue now and then. Restarting Xcode is the only fix I've found – hugely annoying Interface Builder bug. Have you filed a radar?

Comment: I had this problem after an upgrade to Xcode 10.3.  I fixed it by restarting the computer.

Answer (score 1):

Try cleaning your project using "Command + K" 
and run your project again!
Hope it works!

Comment: Hi Madhur, my project compiles and works, only thing is its not showing UI components in storyboard. Clean did not help.

Comment: @happycoder hey! Try restarting your device, it can work!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue that you are facing in my case i had `xCode 10.0` installed and everything was working fine. As soon as I installed version `10.1` I faced the same issue that you're facing but the good thing was i had `xCode 10.0` installed at the same time so I switched back and everything was working fine.

From my point of view my system`(Mac-mini mid 2011)` was lacking hardware specification that was required for `xCode 10.1` also had very **low graphic processor** in my mac mini. If you install the same version in a MacBook or any other system having higher specification you'll face the issue. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck on this all day. One of my coworkers suggested removing occurrences of IB_DESIGNABLE & @IBDesignable. This fixed the issue for me. It still lags sometimes but doesn’t go invisible anymore.

Comment: I tried this, didn't work for me. Still having same issue

Answer (score -1):

If you have multiple xib files then just try to switch between or Try moving to launchScreen storyboard and then switch to main storyboard. I think this is just loading issue.

Comment: He's not looking to add new UI elements but how to see the one he has already added

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the issue and should be removed from this forum.

Answer (score -2):

Reinstall Xcode. That worked for me.

Comment: OP says "Then I tried installing macOs Mojave and install XCode 10 again" in their question. Obviously just reinstalling Xcode is not the solution for them.

Answer (score -3):

Click on library button(Circular Button) which is left to hamburger sign(Top Bar Right Side). Elements will be popup on your screen then you can choose elements.

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the issue and should be removed.

Answer (score -8):

try

```
xcrun simctl erase all
```

it helped me with the same problem

Comment: Do NOT run this command. Not funny. This answer should be removed from public view because it’s malicious advice.