# Xcode 10 Drag and Drop and option-drag on components tree panel not working

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode10

Up until I installed Xcode 10 beta (and now the released version) I used to be able to drag and drop on the components tree (left panel on the storyboard) and option-drag to define constraints. Now, it seems as if dragging is enabled but not dropping, and so I cannot move items in and out of containers, or drag/drop between the panel and the storyboard as usual.

[image]

Why this might be happening?

Comment: Please check if this can solve your problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52637441/xcode-10-storyboard-ui-components-are-not-visible-and-painfully-slow/52737066#52737066

Comment: Unfortunately no :(

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same problem in Xcode 10.1 beta version
.Just Simply add class name and storyboardId, to that ViewController drag and drop will start work.