# Black screen on viewController in IB, Xcode 12.4

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm updated Xcode to version 12.4 (12D4e), MacOS 10.15.7, open my project, and see it:
[image]

All elements lost labels, have black background (don't change from IB) and blue borders. If i add new element on viewController - i get same thing.
In Simulator and real iPhone all works fine, but in IB - that problem.
Clean build folder, restart Xcode and MacOS not working.
Does anyone know how to fix it? Thx

**UPDATE, with solution this problem:**
I'm rolled back last commit in project and problem disappeared. Maybe, that happens, because i'm used in last commit custom class with @IBDesignable properties and delete him later, before commit on Github and update Xcode. I found similar problem and answer, on this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/56121110/13110274
Now all works correctly

Comment: Force quit Xcode ----
--> Go to Application folder
--> Select Xcode
--> Right click
--> Get Info
--> uncheck "Open using Rosetta" --> Open Xcode and You can see the result

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to select and deselect bound rectangles from "Adjust Editor options" in your storyboard?

[image]

Also, it seems your storyboard overstuffed. I recommend you separate it into few views.

Comment: Thx for answer. Yes, select/deselect Bounds rectangles removes blue borders, and deselect Device Bezels removes black background. But content of VC still unseen :(